# Auto-generate employee ID using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm working on a web app project using MEAN stack technology. I want to generate 'empId' (employee ID) *automatically* when a request to add a new employee is received. How can I do the same and store the generated 'empId' in the *same document where I keep employee details*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are other requirements that haven't been stated, you can simply generate `empId` when handling the request to add a new employee, and include it with other properties that may be supplied by the caller:

```
const schema = new Schema({ name: String, empId: String });
const Employee = model('Employee', schema);

// then when handling an "add employee" request:

const { name } = req.body; // properties from request
const empId = generateEmployeeId(); // e.g., "uuid()"
const employee = new Model({name, empId})
```

You can also automatically include an `empId` with each new [Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) by supplying it as a default in the mongoose Schema. Combine that with a library like [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/#mongoose) (that gives you a bit more control over the ids generated) and you would have something like:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  empId: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid()
  }
})
```

Also keep in mind that mongodb will always create a unique identifier for each document [in the _id property](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).

Comment: You'd have to be careful using nanoid as default value, it could lead to duplicates in db. (It's rare but not impossible)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the code using nanoid and presave feature of mongoose.

The code below generates a user friendly id that can be used for many different utilities.

The only potential issue is if the loop keeps finding same id due to the huge amount of users in db(this should not be an issue most apps), this issue can be reduced by either increasing the size of custom alphabets or by just adding more custom characters.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid/async'

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, empId: String });
const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', schema);

employeeSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890abcdefABCDEF', 10)
    let unique = true
    let id = ''
    while (unique) {
      id = await nanoid()
      const user = await Employee.findOne({ empId: id })
      if (!user) {
        unique = false
      }
    }
    this.empId = id
  }
  next()
})
```